# Usecase for assigning append(mySlice, x) to a different slice?

Tags: go

I read [Golang slices gotcha](https://blog.allegro.tech/2017/07/golang-slices-gotcha.html),
and now I ask myself if there are valid usecases for assigning the result of `append()` to a different variable.

Is there a use-case for using this golang code?

```
foo = append(bar, x)
```

Comment: Use different variables when later code uses both the original slice and the result of append.

Comment: @BellinghamBoss since it depends on the capacity of the slice if `bar` gets altered or not, things are not obvious. Up to now I only saw warnings, that you always should assign the result of append() to the same variable again.

Comment: Assigning the result of append to a new variable is akin to writing `foo = bar + x` instead of `bar = bar + x` where `foo`, `bar` and `x` are numbers. Sometimes you want a variable on hand with the original value.  The wrinkle with slices is that assignments to elements in one slice may or may not be seen through the other slice.  In that scenario, more care is needed when using two variables.

Comment: You could use `&foo[0] == &bar[0]` afterwards to check if the location in memory has changed. Obviously only works if `bar` already had at least one element but it is more reliable than checking `cap(bar) == len(bar)` beforehand since in theory the underlying array could be expanded in place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I saw once (from memory). The header slice does not change but is repeatedly appended to.

```
    schemes := []string{
        "Basic",
        "Bearer",
        "Digest",
    }
    header := []byte("Www-Authenticate:")
    for _, scheme := range schemes {
        w.Write(append(header, scheme...))
    }
```

Note this also uses a special feature of `append` that allows a string to be treated as `[]byte`.